# Materialize CSS vertical align distorting width

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, materialize

I am trying to make a searchbar in the middle of a page vertically and ofcourse horizontally.

For some reason when use the built in valign-wrapper it is distorting the width of the search bar.

Why is this happening?
When i do not add the valign-wrapper class the width is ok but when i add it the width becomes very small.

Here is a snippet of what i am doing
https://jsfiddle.net/4khz9jgp/3/

```
<div class="section search-section">
  <div class="valign-wrapper">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col l8 push-l2 m8 push-m2 s10 push-s1">
              <div class="input-field">
                  <input id="icon_prefix" type="text" class="validate" placeholder="type in what you are looking for...">
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to override flex from valign-wrapper on the input field so that it does not take the minimum width possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about you make the `width: 100%;` for the `row` div.

```
<div class="section search-section">
    <div class="valign-wrapper">
        <div id="thisOne" class="row">
            <div class="col l8 push-l2 m8 push-m2 s10 push-s1">
                <div class="input-field">
                    <input id="icon_prefix" type="text" class="validate" placeholder="type in what you are looking for...">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.search-section{
    min-height: 300px;
    height: 100%;
}
#thisOne{
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: This is perfect! I tried doing everything but it seems i missed the 100% on the row for some reason. Hope its reliable also for responsiveness anyways thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is because valign-wrapper has display: flex; property. This means that the input will occupy the minimum space needed.

Maybe you can create another class to center the input, like:

```
.center {
 position: absolute;top:50%;left:50%;transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: tried it on the input-field but now it is not vertiacally alligning